# domain name system domain does not exist

Tags: domain-name-system

I’m not receiving emails on my business gmail account domain. When people message me they get a bounce back message. How can this be solved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1imun.jpg)

Comment: Well, the domain does not exist. Check with your DNS provider if it's just missing records.

Comment: By configuring things correctly. Start by reading [google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en).

Comment: Nominet https://www.nominet.uk/lookup/ lists under Nameservers `The Registrar has configured the domain to not function in the DNS by setting 'client hold'` which according to https://registrars.nominet.uk/uk-namespace/registration-and-domain-management/registration-systems/epp/uk-epp-status-fields/ means `Removes the domain from the zone file.`. So there may be more wrong with your domain/DNS records than just some missing MX records.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain has no MX record, create an MX record pointing to the mail server hostname (ex: mail.exemple.com).

Comment: No, this is not the issue. Not an MX doesn't exists but the whole domain isn't published into DNS. If only MX was missing there will be attempts to deliver using domain A record.